# Why doesn't a Rails 3.2.2 new application include lib/assets in the asset paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently wrote a blog post on the [asset pipeline](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/24/asset-pipeline-for-dummies/) and learned that the folder `lib/assets` should be included in the asset paths list. If I create a brand new Rails app using 3.2.2, run the console and then run the command `y Rails.application.config.assets.paths` I don't see lib/assets. Shouldn't this be included by default?

Here's how I got there:

```
$ rails new example
$ cd example
$ rails c
>> y Rails.application.config.assets.paths
---
- /Users/eberry/Playground/example/app/assets/images
- /Users/eberry/Playground/example/app/assets/javascripts
- /Users/eberry/Playground/example/app/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/eberry/Playground/example/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /Users/eberry/Playground/example/vendor/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/eberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /Users/eberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
=> nil
>>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For those interested, [here is the relevant portion of the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization).

Comment: could be a design decision?  to keep the number of paths to a minimum.  Maybe the designers felt lib/assets would not be used unless the application developer put some of his own code in /lib,  so he'd have to enable /lib based assets?  lib/vendor is there by default because that's where gem developers would normally put their stuff.  Just a guess

Comment: The source code in Rails can be found at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L574. It doesn't seem that they excluded it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Rails installed on this computer, but from the source reference it looks like `lib/assets` would never be included, but any subpaths would.

Try creating `lib/assets/javascripts` and see if that's included automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything in any of the lib folders? I have one js file in my lib/assets/javascripts folder and when I check my asset paths, only that one path, ie lib/assets/javascripts/, is displayed, though not lib/assets/images or lib/assets/stylesheets, since I did not create those folders.

I'm on Rails 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Put at least one file, for example in `lib/assets/javascripts`, then restart your app.

Now `rails c`, and `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` should contain `lib/assets/javascripts`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on rails 3.2
you have to put your scripts into the folder
"assets/javascripts"
and they will get included, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Any subfolder (not just stylesheets/images/javascripts) you create under lib/assets will be added to the load path.

Tested with rails 3.2.11.

Use "rails c"  and type "y Rails.application.config.assets.paths" to verify the asset path.

I suppose its the same thing with vendor/assets and app/assets too, but I havent verified that.